# Class.getClasses() not working with inherited classes from interface

Tags: java, reflection

Can someone explain why `test()` passes while `testInheritance()` not ?

```
public class IPanDeviceEnclosedClassesTest {

    public static interface Root {
       class Enclosed {}
    }

    public static interface Leaf extends Root {}

    @Test
    public void testInheritance() {
        Class<?> enclosing  = Leaf.class;
        Class<?>[] enclosed = enclosing.getClasses();
        assertNotEquals(0, enclosed.length);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Class<?> enclosing  = Root.class;
        Class<?>[] enclosed = enclosing.getClasses(); // getDeclaredClasses() works as well
        assertNotEquals(0, enclosed.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that interfaces are implicitly static.

Comment: Are you missing a bracket for `Root`?

Comment: @PaulBellora : I know about interfaces, and that class Enclosed is then implicitly `public static`. Does this prevents `Class.getClasses()` to work as I ask ? And if yes why ?

@SotiriosDelimanolis : no

Comment: @AntoineMarques I meant the interfaces themselves, but yeah, you're right that `Enclosed` is implicitly public static.

Comment: This was a great question. You would think declaring `Leaf extends Root` meant `Root` was the superclass of `Leaf` - but interfaces have no superclass, at least according to `getSuperclass`. This does make sense since you could declare `Leaf extends Root, RandomAccess, ...` etc.

Comment: I think in this case using the keyword "extends" for super interfaces of an interface is misleading. Anyways, the documentation was exact as pointed by @cyon, I missed the point about super classes only (and not interfaces) by reading not carefully enough :s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the highlighted bit from the `getClasses` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClasses%28%29)

> Returns an array containing Class objects representing all the public classes and interfaces that are members of the class represented by this Class object. This includes public class and interface members **inherited from superclasses** and public class and interface members declared by the class.

From what I can tell, `getClasses()` returns classes that it inherits from a superclass as well as the static classes of its superclass. An interface is not a superclass, so as per the javadoc we shouldn't expect that any static classes declared on the interface will be returned.

Out the following inheritance tests, only `testInheritanceClasses` passes.

1) Class extending a superclass sees `Enclosed`:

```
public static class RootClass {
      public static class Enclosed {}
}

public static class LeafClass extends RootClass {}

@Test
public void testInheritanceClasses() {
    Class<?> enclosing  = LeafClass.class;
    Class<?>[] enclosed = enclosing.getClasses();
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(enclosed));
    Assert.assertNotEquals(0, enclosed.length);
}
```

2) Interface "extending" an interface does not see `Enclosed`

```
public interface Root {
    class Enclosed {}
}

public interface Leaf extends Root {}

@Test
public void testInheritanceInterfaces() {
     Class<?> enclosing  = Leaf.class;
     Class<?>[] enclosed = enclosing.getClasses();
     System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(enclosed));
     Assert.assertNotEquals(0, enclosed.length);
}
```

3) Class implementing an interface does not see `Enclosed`:

```
public interface Root {
    class Enclosed {}
} 

public static class LeafImplementingRoot implements Root {}        


@Test
public void testInheritanceImplements() {
    Class<?> enclosing  = LeafImplementingRoot.class;
    Class<?>[] enclosed = enclosing.getClasses();
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(enclosed));
    Assert.assertNotEquals(0, enclosed.length);
}
```

Comment: +1 And here's [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Class.java#Class.getClasses%28%29) to verify this. I would reword this though: "but it doesn't inherit anything from the interface. It merely implements the interface." It sounds like you're saying interfaces members aren't inherited (which they are).

Comment: @PaulBellora Thanks. I will try to reword to make it more clear. Unfortunately, inheriting is a word with overloaded ( :) ) meaning. To me in Java it means reusing code through a superclass relationship, which does not happen with interfaces. After all, there's no such thing as multiple inheritance but you can have multiple interfaces.